# Interact with UIView coordinates

Tags: uiview

Suppose I have a UIView that is 100x100 points and is aligned to the top left at 0x0. If I move it to the left 50 points, it's new position will be -50x0. Is there anyway to interact with the coordinate system such that I could mod the coordinates by some value and have the UIView behave a bit like a conveyer belt? If I move it out of bounds, the part of the view which was moved out of bounds just appears out the other side?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If what you are asking for is similar to a MARQUEE in the html world.  I recommend you look at this post [scrolling text](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/45541-scrolling-text-horizontally.html) as an example.  There is sample code towards the end that does something like what you are asking about.